# Angular 7 and ASP.NET MVC integration - Styles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular

I am attempting to call and Angular 7 app from a .cshtml Razor page in ASP.NET MVC. The app loads but does not apply styles. I have my Angular app building to a Bundles folder in my MVC solutions root. My BundlesConfig.cs looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Script/Bundles")
           .Include(
           "~/bundles/main.*",
           "~/bundles/polyfills.*",
           "~/bundles/scripts.*",
           //"~/bundles/styles.*",
           "~/bundles/vendor.*",
           "~/bundles/runtime.*"
           ));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Styles")
            .Include("~/bundles/styles.*"));
    }`
```

Index.cshtml looks like this:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<my-component></my-component>
```

Finally, my _Layout.cshtml is like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello World - ASP.NET MVC</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Styles")
</head>
<body>
    <main role="main" class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
   @Scripts.Render("~/Script/Bundles")
</body>
</html>
```

The only styles file ending up in my Bundles folder is styles.js and I am not sure if this is the root of the issue. I tried manually moving the styles.scss file to the bundles and referencing that at one point and that failed too.  As you can see I commented out the styles.* from the script bundle, but I tried it with it uncommented too. That also failed. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Build the angular application from the cli and look at the resulting `index.html` file, copy the references you see there. Do note that the resulting file can have a different structure if you build it with the production flag.

Comment: Adding on to @Igor the order in which you reference these files can determine if your app runs correctly/at all.

Comment: The files in the Script bundle do match the ones in the index.html which is also in the Bundles folder.

Comment: You can also open up the browser's development console and view the resources. Are they the same between the expected index.html and what is being loaded from bundles? Personally I do not like the bundle feature in MVC, I chose to add the angular files directly to the `index.cshtml` (or whatever file is your root .cshtml file) and figure out the correct file names in an Html helper on startup.

Comment: I just fixed the order to match the index file - the result was the same unfortunately.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-angular-project-using-mvc/

Comment: May I suggest to ignore the bundling capabilities and just go for a straight `<link ... />` tag? do an ng build. You can copy the link from the `index.html` generated from ng build and just adjusting the paths. Then: is the css file in the dist folder? if it's not, or if there is a styles.js, it means you have to adjust the Angular build. If it's there, check you have it copied over your `/Content/Styles` folder.

Comment: I did eventually use the <script> tag and dumped the bundling. It turned out I needed to move my assets folder to the root of the solution to access the .svg files the app was looking for, that was why it appeared some of my styles were missing, it was just resources!  Thank you for helping me think it through.